# I don't understand how to print scrapy data in a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I've seen several things, but I'm not able to play this in a table or .csv to print the table on the screen, can anyone help me?

I'm lost

```
import scrapy

class SinonimoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sinonimo'
    start_urls = ['https://www.sinonimos.com.br/pedido/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.css('.sinonimo'):
            yield{
                'sinonimo': i.css('a.sinonimo ::text').get()

            }
```

Comment: You haven't marked your previous question as being answered..... In fact you have hardly marked any of your questions as being answered

Comment: sorry, I will still answer, you answer was very useful, the day was busy, when I get home, I will answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are unable to see the data and want the spider to store the data in CSV?
There are many ways to do it.
The most popular one that we use when we run the spider from the terminal

```
$ scrapy crawl sinonimo -O sinonimo.csv # in case of CSV
$ scrapy crawl sinonimo -O sinonimo.json # in case of json
```

If you need any help, just leave a comment.